# insert a character into a string at old index with itertools [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, lambda, python-itertools

I drop spaces in a string.
I swap the string.

After the swap I whant to put back the spaces at old index.
I whant to achive this with `itertools`. Is it possible?

the reason I use lambdas is becuse I whant to run the function n times at that order.
and I whant to use them later in other functions too.

my code looks like this:

```
import itertools
def func(n, strng):
    
    space_delete = lambda temp_var_strng: temp_var_strng.split(" ")
    join_char = lambda x: "".join(space_delete(x))
    swap_char = lambda s: "".join([join_char(s)[item-n] for item in range(len(join_char(s))) ])
    insert_space = lambda insert: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.repeat(" "), insert)))
    print(swap_char(strng))
```

if my input is `func(4, "hello world")`, swap_char should swap the string 4 times at right.

my `swap_char` gives me `"orldhellow"` so if I put back all the spaces back in old index it should go between orld and hellow.

my last function gives me this **output**:

```
[' ', 'o', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'l', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'h', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'l', ' ', 'l', ' ', 'o', ' ', 'w']
```

but my goal is to get:

```
["orld", " ", hellow]
```

if I do a nested loop like this, the task is solved:

```
for o in lst:
        for i in o:
            result += s[cnt]
            cnt += 1
        result += " "
```

can I achive this in a list comprehension and use that instead, I whant to take the `itertools` solution becuse of the time efficiency.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "swap string" means? please, provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @buran hi, I have made so edits. the swap_char function is doing what it should. the last function (insert_space) does not.

Comment: Inserting the space into the old index (5), would give `["orldh", " ", "ellow"]`.  So what are your rules on spaces?

Comment: Lets say have string that sats ”the Quick Brown fox jumps over the lazy dog”. It wont be just one index. So a space should be inserted in [3, 9, 15, ...] i can get indiencies with [ i for i in range(len(str)) of str[i] == ” ”] but it arena the Time complexity Is not effective.

Comment: Itertools is not more time efficient than a loop... list comprehensions *are loops* essentially. I think your fundamental assumptions about performance are flawed. Also, you shouldn't assign the result of lambda expressions to a name, that defeats *their only purpose* which is to be anonymous. Official style recommendations would be to just use a full function definition.

Comment: And if you cared about efficiency you wouldn't do someting like this: `"".join([join_char(s)[item-n] for item in range(len(join_char(s))) ])` where you needlessly re-compute `join_char(s)`

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, `join_char` is just an inefficient implementation of `my_string.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i’m exprementing with the fundamentals. I have solved the task it self. I used replace wich actually did the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy to solve this.

Input: string = Hello World; n = 4;

Expected Output: orldH elloW

**Python snippet:**

```
import numpy as np

# input
n = 4
string = list("Hello World")

string = np.array(string)

# Find the index of space char " "
space_index = np.where(string==' ')[0]

# Remove the space
string = np.delete(string, space_index)

# Rotate the string by n chars
string = np.concatenate((string[-(n):], string[:-(n)]))

# Add the space char to their original positions
string = np.insert(string, space_index, [' '])

print("".join(string))
```